# show and hide columns in the table by clicking checkbox using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a table with large number of columns, I need to be able to show and hide some columns by clickin checkbox. I've tried a lot of variations of ng-click--ng-show, $scope$watch and now I've trying to do this by addEventListener, but It doesn't work, nothing happend.

```
 $scope.showTheItem = false;

    function newFunction() {
        document.getElementById("showTheItemEvent").addEventListener('checked', function () {
            $scope.showTheItem = true;
            $scope.digest();
        });
    }
```

and this is html:

```
<form ng-show="showTheForm">  // this is the form with checkboxes
            <table onload="newFunction();">
                <tr><td style="vertical-align:top" ng-repeat="item in superKeys" ng-if="$even"><input type="checkbox" id="showTheItemEvent" ng-true-value="checked" style="margin-left:3px; margin-right:15px"><label>{{localization.setLicTabs[locale][item]}}</label></td></tr>
                <tr style="height:10px"></tr>
                <tr><td style="vertical-align:top" ng-repeat="item in superKeys" ng-if="$odd"><input type="checkbox" id="showTheItemEvent" ng-true-value="checked" style="margin-left:3px; margin-right:15px"><label>{{localization.setLicTabs[locale][item]}}</label></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
           <th ng-show="showTheItem">{{localization.setLicTabs[locale].VirtualType}}</th>
                    <th ng-show="showTheItem">{{localization.setLicTabs[locale].FarmName}}</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody dir-paginate="item in dataObjHosts | filter:searchFilter | orderBy:orderListType:true | itemsPerPage: pageSize" pagination-id="POPaginatorServersSoft" current-page="currentPage" ng-click="setActiveState($event)">
                <tr >
                    <td ng-show="showTheItem"><span ng-bind="dataObj[item][0].VirtualType"></span></td>
                    <td ng-show="showTheItem"><span ng-bind="dataObj[item][0].FarmName"></span></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: @Dasha can you `console.log()` something inside `newFunction()` and see if the function is getting called?

Comment: have you tried with simply something like `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showTheItem">` so that the checkbox toggles directly the value of your controller variable?

Comment: @ theapologist  I've put  console.log("this is working") as first action in function, and  console.log($scope.showTheItem) as last action inside the inner function and I've findout that it doesn't called, so I put  $timeout, and know it getting called,  but nothing happend anyway, and it doesn't do the second console.log(), so I've tried to change "checked" to "click" , and in that case It says what object doesn't support method $digest...

Comment: @Kaddath, yes, I've tried that, it works with showing and hiding form with checkboxes and with table rows, but not with table columns

Comment: @ Mayank Vadiya, It seems very cool stuff, I will try it, thanks!!!

Comment: it should work with columns too if it works with rows, maybe there was a mistake in your code. Aside that, if you want `newFunction` to be called, you should put it in the scope: `$scope.newFunction = function(){ ... };`